# getting error AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'getitems'

Tags: python, sqlite, object, tkinter, attributeerror

i keep getting the error AttributeError :

> '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'getitems'

i think this is because the subroutines cannot communicate with each other i have tried assigning get_items as a global variable with no results. i am trying to make a button that collects the entries in the `GUI` enters them into a database with `Sql Lite` for an inventory system for a car dealership.

```
from tkinter import* 
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("E:\computing project\database of cars.db")
c=conn.cursor()



class Database:
    def __init__ ( kwargs , self, master=None ,*args):
        self.master = master
        self.heading = Label(master , text = "add to the database ", font=("ariel 35 bold") )
        self.heading.place (x=250 , y=0)

        self.name= Label(master, text= "enter product name", font=("arial 18 bold"))
        self.name.place(x=0,y=50)



        self.make_1=  Label(master , text = "enter car make ", font=("ariel 18 bold"))
        self.make_1.place(x=0,y=100)

        self.model_1=  Label(master , text = "enter car model ", font=("ariel 18 bold"),)
        self.model_1.place(x=0,y=150)

        self.regi_1=  Label(master , text = "enter registration plate", font=("ariel 18 bold"))
        self.regi_1.place(x=0,y=200)

        self.colour_1=  Label(master , text = "enter car colour ", font=("ariel 18 bold"))
        self.colour_1.place(x=0,y=250)


        self.cost_1=  Label(master , text = "enter cost price ", font=("ariel 18 bold"))
        self.cost_1.place(x=0,y=300)

        self.tcost_1=  Label(master , text = "enter total cost price ", font=("ariel 18 bold"))
        self.tcost_1.place(x=0,y=350)

        self.sell_1=  Label(master , text = "selling price ", font=("ariel 18 bold"))
        self.sell_1.place(x=0,y=400)

        self.tsell_1=  Label(master , text = "enter total selling price", font=("ariel 18 bold"))
        self.tsell_1.place(x=0,y=450)

        self.assprof_1=  Label(master , text = "enter total selling price", font=("ariel 18 bold"))
        self.assprof_1.place(x=0,y=500)




                #button to add to db

      #  b = Button( command=self.get)
       # b.place(x=0,y=0)

                #entry boxes

        self.name_e = Entry(master, width=25, font=("arial 18 bold"))
        self.name_e.place(x=300, y=50)

        self.name_e = Entry(master, width=25, font=("arial 18 bold"))
        self.name_e.place(x=300, y=100)

        self.name_e = Entry(master, width=25, font=("arial 18 bold"))
        self.name_e.place(x=300, y=150)

        self.name_e = Entry(master, width=25, font=("arial 18 bold"))
        self.name_e.place(x=300, y=200)

        self.name_e = Entry(master, width=25, font=("arial 18 bold"))
        self.name_e.place(x=300, y=250)

        self.name_e = Entry(master, width=25, font=("arial 18 bold"))
        self.name_e.place(x=300, y=300)

        self.name_e = Entry(master, width=25, font=("arial 18 bold"))
        self.name_e.place(x=300, y=350)

        self.name_e = Entry(master, width=25, font=("arial 18 bold"))
        self.name_e.place(x=300, y=400)

        self.name_e = Entry(master, width=25, font=("arial 18 bold",))
        self.name_e.place(x=300, y=450)

        self.name_e = Entry(master, width=25, font=("arial 18 bold"))
        self.name_e.place(x=300, y=500)

        self.b = Button(command=self.getitems)
        self.b.place(x=0,y=0)


    def get_items(self,*args,**kwargs):  #this function gets the items from the entry boxes

        self.carmake=self.carmake_e.get()
        self.carmodel=self.carmodel_e.get()
        self.registrationplate=self.registrationplate_e.get()
        self.carcolour=self.carcolour_e.get()
        self.costprice=self.costprice_e.get()
        self.totalprice=self.totalprice_e.get()
        self.sellingprice=self.sellingprice_e.get()
        self.assumedprofit=self.assumedprofit_e.get()


        if self.carmake == '' or self.carmodel == '' == self.carcolour == '':
            print ("WRONG")

        else:
            print("solid m8 ")




root = Tk()
b = Database(root)
frame = Frame(root,width=1920,height=1080)
root.geometry("1920x1080")
root.title("add to database")
root.configure(background="#b7b7e5")
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two mistakes:

**First:** you define method `get_items` (with `_` in name) but you use `command=self.getitems`  (without `_` in name)

```
 self.b = Button(command=self.get_items)
```

**Second:** you have arguments in wrong order is

```
__init__(kwargs, self, master=None, *args)
```

so it assigns class instance to variabla `kwargs` instead of `self` and it assigns `root` to `self` and later it has problem to find `self.get_items` because it means `root.get_items`

`kwargs` should be at the end, and `self` at the beginning

```
__init__(self, master=None, *args, **kwargs)
```